# Text arrangement for CV

Tags: sectioning, positioning, minipage

I am creating a CV Template. I need to create a command in the latex cls file and I need to add that command in tex file like below

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 
\section{Experience}
\cvexperience{JOB Title}{Company}{Place}{Year}{Description blah blah}
\end{minipage}
```

and the cv preview should be like below. [image]

I don't know how to create a command for `\cvexperience` in cls file. Please help me to design the cv section like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what font you are using, but I got something similar, I hope it will helpful:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{lipsum}


 
 
 \newcommand{\cvexperience}[5]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.79\textwidth}
     \begin{flushleft}
     \textbf{\texttt{#1}}  \\ 
     \textbf{\textcolor{gray}{#2 $\vert  $ #3}}\\
      #5
     \end{flushleft}
     \end{minipage} 
 \hfill
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.15\textwidth}
\vspace{.5cm}
  \textcolor{gray}{\small{#4}}
\end{minipage} 

}
 
 
\begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 
  \cvexperience{JOB Title}{Company}{Place}{Jun'19 -- Dec'19}{\lipsum[1]} 
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Job title and year are not in the same horizontal line. The year went little above in horizontal level

Comment: @Sabesan now should be better